# How to get all records from previous year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

My code is producing current year's rows instead of previous year's rows in the last year column

```
DECLARE @prevYear int
DECLARE @prevMonth int

SELECT @prevYear = DATEPART(year, GETDATE() - 1)
SELECT @prevMonth = DATEPART(month, GETDATE() - 30)

SELECT  
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(month, [OrderDate]) = @prevMonth  
                THEN Amount 
                ELSE 0 
        END) AS 'LastMonth',    
    SUM(Amount) AS 'LastYear'
FROM 
    Orders
INNER JOIN 
    OrderDetail ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetail.OrderID 
WHERE 
    DATEPART(year, [OrderDate]) = @prevYear
```

I'm expecting to get previous year (2022) row in last year column

Comment: FYI, syntax like `WHERE DATEPART(year, [OrderDate]) = @prevYear` is not SARGable. Use date ranges, don't use functions on your columns.

Answer (score 0):

You would be far better off working out the year and then using `DATEFROMPARTS` for a SARGable clause:

```sql
DECLARE @prevYear int;
DECLARE @prevMonth int;

SELECT @prevYear = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())-1;
SELECT @prevMonth = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()));

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month,O.OrderDate) = @prevMonth THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS LastMonth,  --Dont use single quote aliases
       SUM(OD.Amount) AS LastYear
FROM Orders O
INNER JOIN dbo.OrderDetail OD ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID 
WHERE O.OrderDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(@PrevYear,1,1) --Alias guessed
  AND O.OrderDate < DATEFROMPARTS(@PrevYear+1,1,1);
```

All column qualifiers are assumed.

Comment: I've applied your codes but it didn't work. So I have modified my codes as SELECT @prevYear = DATEPART(year, GETDATE() - 360) and it works fine

Comment: That isn't a year though... What does "doesn't work" mean, as they won't work on a date like 2023-12-29.